# Slow Form on Access connecting to VPS to load 2 Comboboxes

Tags: mysql, ms-access, odbc

As the title says I have a form in access that I use for data entry. This form has to load 2 comboboxes one for suplier name the other for location name. The other thing it does is check if user has access to the form. This is on the load event.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
'Verify User Access
If Globales.Accesos(Me.Name) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No tiene accesos a esta area."
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
End If

'Set Null Values
    Me.Text14 = Null
    Me.Text16 = Null
    Me.Text18 = Null
    Me.Combo26 = Null
    Me.Text73 = Null
    Me.Text28 = Null
    Me.Text50 = Null
    Me.Text42 = Null
    Me.Text46 = Null
    Me.Text44 = Null
    Me.Text40 = Null
    Me.Text48 = Null
    Me.Text30 = Null
    Me.Text36 = Null
    Me.Text38 = Null
    Me.Text52 = Null
    Me.Text54 = Null
    Me.Text75 = Null

'Set Combobox Localidades Values
Dim db2 As DAO.Database
Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset
Dim SQL2 As String

    Set db2 = OpenDatabase("", False, False, Globales.ConnString)

    SQL2 = "SELECT tbl5localidades.ID, tbl5localidades.NombreLocalidad FROM tbl5localidades;"
    Set rs2 = db2.OpenRecordset(SQL2, dbOpenDynaset, dbReadOnly)
    With Text18
    .RowSourceType = "Value List"
    .BoundColumn = 1
    .ColumnCount = 2
    .ColumnWidths = "0;1in"
    End With
    With rs2
    .MoveFirst
    Do Until .EOF
    Text18.AddItem !ID & ";" & !NombreLocalidad
    .MoveNext
    Loop
    End With

    rs2.Close
    Set rs2 = Nothing

'db2.Close
'Set db2 = Nothing

   'Set Combobox Suplidores Values
Dim db3 As DAO.Database
Dim rs3 As DAO.Recordset
Dim SQL3 As String

 Set db3 = OpenDatabase("", False, False, Globales.ConnString)

    SQL3 = "SELECT tbl6suplidores.ID, tbl6suplidores.NombreSuplidor FROM tbl6suplidores ORDER BY tbl6suplidores.NombreSuplidor;"
    Set rs3 = db3.OpenRecordset(SQL3, dbOpenDynaset, dbReadOnly)
    With Combo26
    .RowSourceType = "Value List"
    .BoundColumn = 1
    .ColumnCount = 2
    .ColumnWidths = "0;1in"
    End With
    With rs3
    .MoveFirst
    Do Until .EOF
    Combo26.AddItem !ID & ";" & !NombreSuplidor
    .MoveNext
    Loop
    End With

    rs3.Close
    Set rs3 = Nothing

'db3.Close
'Set db3 = Nothing
End Sub
```

This works as intended but its so slow that get Acces to be unresponsive for about 30sec. Is there anyway to optimize this to load faster?

Comment: Why do you need to loop through recordset as opposed to just setting the RowSource property to SQL statement in form design? Are you not linked to tables in MySQL backend? What is VPS?

Comment: Virtual Private Server. I need to loop through the recordset since the user can add new suppliers or locations that will need to appear there. These are not linked tables these connect directly to the mysql database through ODBC driver. Right now there are only 6 records in the locations combobox and might add 1 or 2 in a year or so. The suplier combobox gets updated more often as there might be new supliers each week the list being of around 50 values not more than that.

Comment: Only 50 items for a combobox list? That should build in a snap. Does form RecordSet data load so slowly?

Comment: [Debugging VBA Code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) -- step through your code to find out where exactly it is taking so long.

Comment: What's `Globales.ConnString`? Are you using DAO to connect to an external ODBC database that way? If so, that's very, very inefficient, use ADO to directly work with non-Access ODBC data sources instead (and directly bind the combo box to the recordset instead of iterating over the recordset).

Answer (score 0):

Well, a “value” list driving a combo box is good for about 100, maybe 200 rows.

After that?

Don’t use a value list. Just shove the sql right into the combo/listbox data source.

Eg:

Me.Text18.Rowsource = "SELECT tbl5localidades.ID, tbl5localidades.NombreLocalidad FROM tbl5localidades;"

In fact, since the sql is not dynamic, then just place the sql right into the row source, and you don’t need any code at all.

You not mentioned how large this table is that drives the combo box, but Access will try and do its best to only pull the on row PK from that list until you open the combo box. So, don’t use “value/list”, but use sql for the combo box. You could also declare the record set at the forms level, and shove that into the combo box on form load as a data source, but using just the sql you have and no code likely will work the best.

A value list also has a hard limit of about 4000 characters, and thus that is another wall you can hit rather easy.

Do NOT use a pass-through query for this – the client cannot optimize the PT query, so a plane Jane linked table, and a plane Jane sql should work just fine.

And, of course change the combo box setting from value list to table/query